# How to remove duplicates in the results?

Tags: sql

My SQL knowledge is pretty basic so this might be a very simple solution, when I run the query there are duplicates in one of the columns 'Service/Project Margin', how do I remove the duplicates (baring in mind I would like the figures in the other column 'Product Margin' to still be displayed (or added together if this is possible)

Here's the SQL:
    -- Detail

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT
    [dbo].[v_api_find_Invoice].[Company_Name] AS 'Company'
   ,[dbo].[v_api_find_Invoice].[Invoice_Number] AS 'id'
   ,SUM(
   ([dbo].[v_rpt_Product].[Quantity] * [dbo].[v_rpt_Product].[unit_price]) -   
   ([dbo].[v_rpt_Product].[Quantity] * [dbo].[v_rpt_Product].[unit_cost])
       ) AS 'Product Margin'
   ,SUM([dbo].[v_rpt_Invoices].[Time_Amount] - 
        [dbo].[v_rpt_Invoices].[Progress_Amount_Applied]
       )  AS 'Service/Project Margin'
   ,[dbo].[v_api_find_Invoice].[DateInvoice] AS 'Date Invoice'
    FROM [dbo].[v_api_find_Invoice] WITH(NOLOCK) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[v_rpt_Product] WITH(NOLOCK)  
      ON [dbo].[v_rpt_Product].[billing_log_recid] = 
         [dbo].[v_api_find_Invoice].[Billing_Log_RecID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[v_rpt_Invoices] WITH(NOLOCK)  
      ON [dbo].[v_rpt_Invoices].[Billing_Log_RecID] = 
         [dbo].[v_api_find_Invoice].[Billing_Log_RecID]
    GROUP BY [dbo].[v_api_find_Invoice].[Invoice_Number]
            ,[dbo].[v_api_find_Invoice].[DateInvoice]
            ,[dbo].[v_api_find_Invoice].[Company_Name]
            ,[dbo].[v_rpt_Invoices].[Time_Amount] - 
             [dbo].[v_rpt_Invoices].[Progress_Amount_Applied]
```

Edit: Here's some example results, you can see the duplicates occuring better (the column the repeated 6000.00's is Service/Project Margin:

80613 Company X 11.65 6000.00 2014-12-30

80613 Company X 36.80 6000.00 2014-12-30

80613 Company X 48.55 6000.00 2014-12-30

Comment: We would need to see some sample data, your current output and expected output.

Comment: my SQL knowledge is pretty limited, but you are doing a select DISTINCT on company_name, but you should also do a DISTINCT or UNIQUE on Service/ Project Margin

Comment: If a selected column is not an argument to a set function (SUM etc), also list it in GROUP BY. (And vice versa...) No need for DISTINCT then.

Comment: It appears, The `time amount` - `progress_Amount_Applied` in your group by is causing the duplicate records since it's in the aggregate sum in the select it shouldn't be in the group by unless you need to group by on an individual record basis.Additionally, a distinct isn't needed with a group by; but I'm sure it's there as you were trying different methods to eliminate the duplicate's but it isn't needed.

Comment: did you try `    SELECT  DISTINCTROW ... `

Comment: What is your DBMS? MySQL, sql server, oracle? It looks like most people in the comments assume MySQL...

Comment: Here's some example data (from the first row):

Company  80613 3759.46 90000.00 2014-12-30

The 3759.46 is absolutely correct but for the 90000.00 it seems to be adding the same values together e.g. 9000 ten times

My expected output would be that it displays 3759.46 (which it is and this is a SUM of all products) and then 9000.00 (a sum of all the labour/project fees)

Comment: @Oscar it would be better to give an example where it DOES NOT meet your expected output.

Comment: How do I do a DISTINCT or UNIQUE on Service/Project Margin?

Comment: @dbagley It is displaying all data correctly for the Product Margin column regardless but in my example above the 90000.00 is incorrect

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't tell it was 90,000.00 vs 9,000.00

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog and @Oscar DISTINCT` operates on rows not columns btw.

Comment: The square braces and `with (nolock)` make it pretty clear this is SQL Server.

Comment: Of course there's the `dbo` also....or do the ticks around column aliases make it Sybase??

Answer (score 0):

Remove this expression from your `GROUP BY`

```
dbo.v_rpt_Invoices.Time_Amount - dbo.v_rpt_Invoices.Progress_Amount_Applied
```

I hope you'll allow me to use aliases to clean up a lot of the noise in there:

```
SELECT
      fi.Company_Name AS Company
    , fi.Invoice_Number AS id
    , SUM(rp.Quantity * (rp.unit_price - rp.unit_cost)) AS "Product Margin"
    , SUM(ri.Time_Amount - ri.Progress_Amount_Applied) AS "Service/Project Margin"
    , fi.DateInvoice AS "Date Invoice"
FROM
    dbo.v_api_find_Invoice WITH (NOLOCK) as fi
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_rpt_Product WITH (NOLOCK) as rp
        ON rp.billing_log_recid = fi.Billing_Log_RecID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_rpt_Invoices WITH (NOLOCK) as ri
        ON ri.Billing_Log_RecID = fi.Billing_Log_RecID
GROUP BY
      fi.Company_Name
    , fi.Invoice_Number
    , fi.DateInvoice
```

Comment: Didn't have any luck removing the expression, instead of dividing the sum it adds them all together e.g. 90000 instead of 6000 fifteen times which is still wrong. I just need it to sum the 6000 once

Can you help?

Comment: Can you show us what some of the data looks like after the joins but prior to the grouping?

Comment: If they're all the same value then just use `min` or `max`. If you expect different values but only want to add the distinct values once that's harder. That can be done with a subquery or by rewriting the query. It would help to understand where this duplication is coming from.

Comment: Absolutely, so instead of showing:


80613 Company X 11.65 6000.00 2014-12-30

80613 Company X 36.80 6000.00 2014-12-30

80613 Company X 48.55 6000.00 2014-12-30'

It shows:

80613 Company X 97.00 18000.00 2014-12-30

So, I am expecting the 6000.00 from "Service/Project Margin" to be returned once but it is there on each row which is causing the SUM to add up wrong

Comment: So you want nulls or zeroes for the last two rows? Which version of SQL Server is this? You were talking about fifteen rows getting summed as well as three rows. I don't understand the fifteen though.

Answer (score -1):

Add the 'Service/Project Margin' column to your GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I tried this but it splits the row into separate rows (I just added the returned results to original post so you can see better). I.e. before it would return 90000 (expecting it to display 6000 once), but with your change it now displays 6000 fifteen times which is still 90000 but split into the separate products from the other column (product margin)

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you need to use a subquery.